# Match subdomain to folder using .htaccees file

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, server, apache2

I'm creating a blogging platform where each user got their own subdomain for their website. So I was thinking is it possible using .htaccess to redirect the user to the directory they entered in the URL.

I'm basically looking for a solution to dynamicaly create a new blog using the platform and when it does that it'll create a new laravel project and that project will have its own subdomain.

E.g.

Blog1.example.com will show the content from /blog1/public

Blog2.example.com and will show the content from /blog2/public

Is that possible or should I look for a different solution?

Im using Apache2 and laravel

Comment: do a Google Search for subdomain wildcards

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. 
First you have to allow/enable wildcard subdomains at your domain registrar/provider's dashboard. 
Then you set your application routes to support subdomain routing.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing

Logic is that you limit no requests to

```
anything.example.com
```

since you've enabled

```
*.example.com
```

at registrar's. If `anything` doesn't exist in you `blogs.slug` column you would

Then you make that sort of filter through laravel's subdomain routing shown in docs at that link above.

```
Route::domain('{slug}.example.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('blog/{slug}', function ($slug) {
        // pseudo code
        //
        // if $slug doesn't exist
        // redirect to some generic or 404 page
    });
    // or
    // Route::get('/blog/{slug}', 'BlogController@show')->name('blog.show');
});
```

In controller you'd have something like

```
BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function show(string $slug)
    {
        $blog = Blog::where(['slug' => $slug])->first();
        return view('blog.show', compact('slug'));
    }
}
// this block is implemented valid way if you use routing call that is commented out `Route::get('/blog/{slug}', 'BlogController@show');` instead anonymous callback function shown before that line in route file.
```

There are other things you can implement such as setting primaryKey in Blog model to be `'slug'` field then you would be able to use implicit model binding with `public function show (Blog $blog) { /** return $blog */ }` etc. but this is something where you can start. Basically no need for `.htaccess` changes.

Comment: What I'm thinking is actually that every time someone creates a new blog I'd run a command that creates a new Laravel application instead of running it all in one Laravel application I'd like to run each blog with's it's own Laravel app using the blog.example.com, blog2.example.com, e.t.c.

Comment: No need for that. What would be the reason for that kind of approach?

Comment: Later on, I would allow users to install their own plugins by building a plugin manager. I'm just thinking if I had to run it on one application running a lot of plugins would be overkill and would be better to separate it into their own app so it doesn't contain too many plugins.

Comment: Lot of wishes without single line of code. You are raising the bar with every new comment. I think nobody on Stackoverflow can help until you have concrete question that explicitly include code of where error happened. Warmly advice to read this article of [how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Or maybe you would like to ask [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (Software Engineering) until you don't have concept and concrete code question for SO community.